# Set Segoe UI Symbol font programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I learn Windows Phone programming. Since I got Lumia 610 (WP7.8), I write in 7.1 SDK. The problem is I want my app to concatenate string with an arrow symbol, which is available in Segoe UI Symbol font. But when I try to force programme programmatically to use Segoe UI Font it doesn't work (it shows only a &#x 2708; string). When I'm forcing using for e.g. Comic Sans MS - there's no problem.

```
this.lExercise.Text = "zxcv";
                this.lExercise.Inlines.Add(new Run()
                {
                    Text = "&#x2708;",
                    FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI Symbol")                       
                });
                this.lExercise.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = " asdf", FontSize = 36 });
```

Any ideas appreciated :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The symbol for a [right arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_%28symbol%29#Arrows_in_Unicode) is `U+2192`. The string you're using (`&#x2708;`) has been escaped so that it can be used in XAML. When using it in code, you use `\u2192` to let it know that it's a symbol. So it should be

```
Text = "\u2192", //or \u2708 if you want the plane symbol
```

Comment: It was an error in my post, I meant the string with code (&#x 2708;) doesn't change into the symbol, when I change the font family...

Comment: It might just be the font set doesn't have the equivalent. See [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx) for the available symbols.

Comment: When I put the &#x 2192; code in XAML its shown in normal way, so it has to be available.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the obvious mistake. The string you're using works because it's in XAML and so it's been escaped. You don't need to escape it in the code, you simply add `\u` to show that it's a symbol. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string content = '\u2708'.ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

From Windows Dev Center::
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font#about-segoe-mdl2-assets

With the release of Windows 10, the Segoe MDL2 Assets font replaced the Windows 8/8.1 Segoe UI Symbol icon font. (Segoe UI Symbol will still be available as a "legacy" resource, but we recommend updating your app to use the new Segoe MDL2 Assets.)